# C 'mmap' causing segmentation fault. Ideas?

Tags: c, mmap, fault

I am trying to write a program that reads a file using 'mmap' for school. I am having some difficulty creating the map. Specifically, I am getting a segmentation fault. I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here so some concrete help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    FILE* fp;// File pointer
    int fd;// File descriptor
    size_t size;// Length of the file
    char* map;// File mmap

    /* Open the file */
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r+");

    /* Get the file descriptor */
    fd = fileno(fp);
    printf("FD: %d\n", fd);

    /* Get the size of the file */
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("SIZE: %d\n", size);

    /* Map the file with mmap */
    map = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, 0, fd, 0);

    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("MMAP FAILED\n");
    } else {
        printf("MMAP SUCEEDED\n");
    }

    /* Do something with the map */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        char c;
        c = map[i];
        putchar(c);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @Jack may have the right answer, but posting a question before even trivial debug steps like checking `fopen()` isn't null strikes me as just lazy.

Answer (score 3):

You are not specifying anything as the flag argument, you must either specify `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED` as specified [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> The flags argument determines whether updates to the mapping are
>          visible to other processes mapping the same region, and whether
>          updates are carried through to the underlying file. This behavior is determined by including exactly one of the following values in flags:
>
> `MAP_SHARED`  Share this mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible to
>                 other processes that map this file, and are carried through to
>                 the underlying file.  (To precisely control when updates are
>                 carried through to the underlying file requires the use of
>                 msync(2).)
>
> `MAP_PRIVATE`
>                 Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the
>                 mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same
>                 file, and are not carried through to the underlying file.  It
>                 is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the
>                 mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.

In your case, since you are just reading the file, `MAP_PRIVATE` should be enough.

Try with:

```
map = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
```

Comment: Excellent this worked for me. I did not understand what the flags were used for. Thank you.